# MSSQL: How to extract binary data compressed into a text field?

Tags: sql-server

Got a weird database I need to kind of reverse engineer. I assume the original data is either RTF or some binary Word document, and it is surely compressed, because we were told by the authors.
The collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS. Why the heck would they store it as text is above me.

So the question is, how could I extract this data? I'm think somehow to convert the text to `varbinary`, then `UNCOMPRESS()`, and somehow export the result into a file.

[image]

Comment: the most common way of store files as varchar is base64Encode them, so try with decoding it

Comment: this obviously is not base64, if you look at all the out-of-range characters.

Comment: _how could I extract this data_ Ask the "authors" who already told you something (but what exactly is not clear).

Comment: yeah, that's not an option. "authors" encrypted their (our) client's data and refuse to provide it unencrypted. sounds like a legal battle to me, but meanwhile I was tasked to try and see if I can decrypt/decompress, whatever. the "authors" only gave this much information.